# Deserialize value that may be an array of strings or a constant string?

Tags: rust, enums, deserialization, serde

I am deserializing some JSON using [Serde](https://serde.rs/). I am having problems with a value that is usually an array of strings, but can also be the constant string `"all"`. Expressed in JSON-schema it looks like this:

```
{
    "oneOf": [
        {
            "const": "all" 
        },
        {
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
                "type": "string"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to serialize it into this enum:

```
enum MyList {
    List(Vec<String>),
    All
}
```

Here are a few examples:

```
["foo", "bar"]  // Should be MyList::List
"all"           // Should be MyList::All
"foo"           // Should be an error!
```

The question is, how do I deserialize this enum using serde? None of the [container attributes](https://serde.rs/container-attrs.html) or [variant attributes](https://serde.rs/variant-attrs.html) seem to help. If need be, I may change the design of the enum. However, the structure of the JSON is beyond my control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible with the combination of an [untagged enum representation](https://serde.rs/enum-representations.html#untagged) and [`deserialize_with` variant attribute](https://serde.rs/variant-attrs.html#deserialize_with):

```
use serde::{Deserialize, Deserializer};

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
// This annotation "flattens" the enum, allowing one to treat a list of strings
// directly as a List variant, without extra annotations.
// Serde will attempt to deserialize input as each variant in order,
// returning an error if no one matches.
#[serde(untagged)]
enum MyList {
    // This annotation delegates deserialization of this variant to own code,
    // since otherwise Serde wouldn't know what to do with the string.
    #[serde(deserialize_with = "all")]
    All,
    // This variant is deserialized as usual.
    List(Vec<String>),
}

// A custom deserialization function, referred to by `deserialize_with`.
// (reference: https://github.com/serde-rs/serde/issues/1158)
fn all<'de, D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<(), D::Error>
where
    D: Deserializer<'de>,
{
    #[derive(Deserialize)]
    // This enum is, by default, "externally tagged";
    // but, since it consists only of a single unit variant,
    // it means that it can be deserialized only from
    // the corresponding constant string - and that's exactly what we need
    enum Helper {
        #[serde(rename = "all")]
        Variant,
    }
    // We're not interested in the deserialized value (we know what it is),
    // so we can simply map it to (), as required by signature
    Helper::deserialize(deserializer).map(|_| ())
}

fn main() {
    // Trying to parse an array with both variants...
    let json = r#"["all", ["a", "b", "c"]]"#;
    let lists: Vec<MyList> = serde_json::from_str(json).expect("cannot parse");
    // ...we can see that it is indeed parsed correctly...
    println!("{:?}", lists);

    // ...and any unexpected string results in an error
    serde_json::from_str::<MyList>(r#""foo""#).unwrap_err();
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=7c4c5bd1b4dabeb72e308ae7f8db9bd1)